# Use multiple materials for merged geometries in Three.js

Tags: javascript, merge, three.js, mesh

I want to create a Pine using 2 meshes, 1 for the trunk and another one for the bush, this what I've done:

```
var pine_geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

var pine_texture_1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./res/textures/4.jpg');
var pine_geometry_1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(25, 25, 50, 6);
var pine_material_1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map : pine_texture_1
});

var pine_1 = new THREE.Mesh(pine_geometry_1);
pine_1.position.x = x;
pine_1.position.y = y + 25;
pine_1.position.z = z;

pine_1.updateMatrix();
pine_geometry.merge(pine_1.geometry, pine_1.matrix);

var pine_texture_2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./res/textures/5.jpg');
var pine_geometry_2 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 70, 250, 8);
var pine_material_2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map : pine_texture_2
});

var pine_2 = new THREE.Mesh(pine_geometry_2);
pine_2.position.x = x;
pine_2.position.y = y + 175;
pine_2.position.z = z;

pine_2.updateMatrix();
pine_geometry.merge(pine_2.geometry, pine_2.matrix);

var pine = new THREE.Mesh(pine_geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial([pine_material_1, pine_material_2]));
pine.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
pine.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

Game.scene.add(pine);
```

The Pine is correctly positioned as I want, however, the whole merged shape only uses 1 material instead of the 2 (the whole shape is covered by the 1st) and I want that each mesh has it's respective material when mergin both.

What I'm doing wrong? any idea?

Comment: `MeshFaceMaterial` has been removed. Use an `Array` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a long research I discovered that I was missing an extra parameter for the method 'merge' from the Geometry object, the last parameter is the **index of the material** that the mesh must have from the materials array, ex: 0 -> first material in 'materials' array... and so on.

So, my final piece of code looks like:

```
pine_geometry.merge(pine_1.geometry, pine_1.matrix, 0);

var pine_texture_2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./res/textures/5.jpg');
var pine_geometry_2 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 70, 250, 8);
var pine_material_2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map : pine_texture_2
});

var pine_2 = new THREE.Mesh(pine_geometry_2);
pine_2.position.x = x;
pine_2.position.y = y + 175;
pine_2.position.z = z;

pine_2.updateMatrix();
pine_geometry.merge(pine_2.geometry, pine_2.matrix, 1);
```

(Note the last numbers I add to each merge).

*However*, I want to clarify that this practice only works when we are dealing with various geometries that are from the same type, in this case, we're merging **two CylinderGeometry**, but if we wanted to merge for example a Cylinder with a Box AND add the MeshFaceMaterial, it wouldn't be recognized properly and the console will throw us 'Cannot read property map/attributes from undefined', nevertheless we can still merge both geometries but not providing multiple materials (that's a terrible mistake I made).

Hope this helps to anyone.

Comment: I'm trying to do this but gets the error three.js:20820 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general function to merge meshes with materials, You can also specify if you want it to return it as a buffer geometry.

```
function _mergeMeshes(meshes, toBufferGeometry) {

    var finalGeometry,
        materials = [],
        mergedGeometry = new THREE.Geometry(),
        mergeMaterial,
        mergedMesh;

    meshes.forEach(function(mesh, index) {
        mesh.updateMatrix();
        mesh.geometry.faces.forEach(function(face) {face.materialIndex = 0;});
        mergedGeometry.merge(mesh.geometry, mesh.matrix, index);
        materials.push(mesh.material);
    });

    mergedGeometry.groupsNeedUpdate = true;
    mergeMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);

    if (toBufferGeometry) {
        finalGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(mergedGeometry);
    } else {
        finalGeometry = mergedGeometry;
    }

    mergedMesh = new THREE.Mesh(finalGeometry, mergeMaterial);
    mergedMesh.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    mergedMesh.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    return mergedMesh;

}

var mergedMesh = _mergeMeshes([trunkMesh, treeTopMesh], true);
```